# android notepad tutorial - no build target available

Tags: android, notepad

when setting up the the notepad exercise (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) i am having problems getting past step 1 point 4. for build target it says no target available.

could someone offer any help please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you building this in Eclipse?

Comment: yes i am building this in eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a silly question, but have you downloaded the SDK and set up Eclipse with ADT?  Have you been able to build the HelloWorld program?

Comment: downloaded the sdk and eclipse with adt and its all installed

Comment: In eclipse goto Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager then click on Installed Packages on the left, it should show the SDK targets available.

Comment: Ok, I think you've installed the basic SDK tools, but not any actual SDK targets.  YOu need to launch the android sdk tools, default in C:\program files\android\android-sdk-windows\ and select the android versions you want to build against.  see: http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html

Comment: hi. please see my 2nd image above for the new problems (sorry to be a pain)

Comment: You may need to right click on the SDK manager and run as administrator?  It seems it doesn't have write access to the drive.

Comment: i'm doing it straight from eclipse. when i click on sdk manager from the directory where i installed it it brings up a cmd and then dissapears. i've tried it as run as admin but it does the same

Comment: Apparently there are various reasons why it would fail: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4410. A popular cause is antivirus software - notably Norton and Kaspersky.

Comment: this is going to sound daft but in that case how do i turn off my anti virus? i have avg and it doesnt say anywhere to quit/close down

Comment: google fu to the rescue! hope this works for your version.
http://www.ehow.com/how_5052104_disable-avg-antivirus.html

Comment: thanks. the the to stop avg has worked. however i'm still getting the same errors as image 2 when i am trying to install. do you have teamviewer? it would be much appreciated if you could directly access my machine and see if you can find out whats wrong

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted in the above comment? There are a few other reasons why it can fail. Look at others' solutions and see if they work for you.

Comment: wooo it seems like its working lol. i copied the tools directory, then ran android.bat as admin from the tools copy directory whilst avg was off and its started to isntall. i shall get back to you once its done.

Comment: ignore my last message. i forgot to restart eclipse. thanks for your help

Comment: <3 awesome! now make me some sweet apps!

Comment: i'll do what i can to help.  they say the best way to learn is to teach!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your Android SDK location in Eclipse->Android preferences.

Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Android->SDK Location

Answer (score 1):

You need to download at least one of the "essential SDK components" into your development environment:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Download one of the **"SDK Platform Android" 1.* or 2.*** from the *Android SDK and AVD Manager* (located on the toolbar towards the left - has a picture of a little Android guy with a down arrow). Once you have one of the platforms installed you will have a Build Target available in the list. I would just go ahead and download any available SDKs that you see in the under "Available".

Answer (score 0):

Non of other answers worked for me. So here a short collection of them my solution at the end.

**Checkliste**

- Android SDK installed? http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html
- SDK Path in Eclipse: Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Android->SDK Location
- Update Eclipse and Android SDK: Help > Check for Updates